# Buffering videos with VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have an Activity that takes a url and plays the video with a VideoView.  This works fine.

However, there is a buffer time before the video starts playing.  Because of this, the VideoView is black.  There is no spinner indicating a buffer loading.

Is there a parameter of the VideoView that will show a spinner?  If not, is there some message that gets broadcast when the video starts playing?  That way I can show my own spinner and hide it when the message is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.  Add a ProgressBar over the top of the VideoView and do the following:

```
    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```